# jQuery: Issues writing a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have this function which is from FancyBox ...

**jQuery**

```
(function ($, F) {
    F.transitions.resizeIn = function() {
        var previous = F.previous,
            current  = F.current,
            startPos = previous.wrap.stop(true).position(),
            endPos   = $.extend({opacity : 1}, current.pos);

    startPos.width  = previous.wrap.width();
    startPos.height = previous.wrap.height();

    previous.wrap.stop(true).trigger('onReset').remove();

    delete endPos.position;

    current.inner.hide();

    current.wrap.css(startPos).animate(endPos, {
        duration : current.nextSpeed,
        easing   : current.nextEasing,
        step     : F.transitions.step,
        complete : function() {
            F._afterZoomIn();

            current.inner.fadeIn("fast");
        }
    });
};
```

and I'd like to call it from simple link. For example like this:

**HTML**

```
<a class="myFunction" href="#gallery">Click here</a>
```

Does anyone have a clue how to do it?

I know it shouldn't be that difficult, but my jQuery/Javascript knowledge is very limited.

**Edit:**

The function is currently called from this link:

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:;">Click here</a>
```

and I need to get rid of the `href="javascript:;"` thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This come's out of the box. Just read the docs : http://fancybox.net/howto

Example taken from FancyBox website :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* This is basic - uses default settings */

    $("a#single_image").fancybox();

/* Using custom settings */

    $("a#inline").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': true
    });

/* Apply fancybox to multiple items */

    $("a.myFunction").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false
    });

});
```

Comment: Did i understand the question right?
Or do you wan't to extend FancyBox with your own plugin/effect???

Comment: I want to call the FancyBox from a custom menu (which has a higher z-index than Fancybox) so people don't need the FB's own navigation anymore.

Comment: You can overwrite/extend everything in fancy box and there's a bunch of settings, which make's it really easy to customize. Have a look at the full documentation to see how to do this on http://fancybox.net/api